# Icon of project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I want certain projects in my solution opened in Visual Studio have different icons..Just like how Visual Studio displays different icons for class project, web site project etc

> I am not talking about changing the icon of the winforms or other such app being produced

I understand I should arrange my code into proper namespaces / folder structure...and can even arrange the project into solution folders...but above will communicate better to my teammate for time being...(unfortunately we have inherited a reasonable code base and things needs to be cleaned along further development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in your SLN file, the project has a guid assigned to it.

all the c# projects have

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}")
```

and all the build folders have ..

```
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}")
```

These define the project type, which you can hunt down in your registry ....

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Projects
```

With this finding, I would say what you are looking for is VERY possible, but you'll have to create custom project types for visual studio. This may not be as daunting as it sounds, if you start with on of the default packages.

Here is a pointer to a sample, where in fact they mention setting the custom icon in step 3.

[Building a Custom Project Wizard in Visual Studio .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289144(VS.71).aspx)